# Spark Split function :

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying the split function for the below List :

[image: click for the image having the issue here]
Can you please let me know what is wrong that I am doing ?

Comment: Please add your code as text. Can you create [mcve]?

Comment: `df2` is of type `String` in your code, and `map` will iterate `Chars`, which have no function `split`.

Comment: scala> df2
res44: String = List(A3AF8FFZAZYNE5, 78, 5.0)

scala>  val df3=df2.map(x => x.split(","))
<console>:30: error: value split is not a member of Char
        val df3=df2.map(x => x.split(","))

Comment: What is the usecase ? Can you update your question with input and output values?

Comment: @jjayadeep sorry for the delayed response. I was doing some hands on example and just trying out incorrectly and as ked above doubt. After knowing its not possible I understood the exact cause.